# PyQt6: Calling worker object method makes program temporarily unresponsive

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6

I'm trying to replicate [this](https://humanbenchmark.com/tests/sequence) with Python and PyQt6. I have been successful in creating a working prototype of it.
**The problem:**
`SequenceMemory.request_round` is a `PyQt6.QtCore.pyqtSignal` that is emitted when the user is to be displayed a new round for the game, be it at the start of the game or after a previous round. However, for some reason, when `request_round` is emitted, the GUI goes unresponsive for about half a second.
I've pin-pointed the problem to the `self.request_round.emit()` line in the `new_round()` method of the `SequenceMemory` class (after commenting out that line the GUI does not go unresponsive), but I can't seem to figure out why this occurs.
I thought the `sleep()` function in the `CreateSequenceWorker` class might be the cause but changing the integer passed to `sleep()` didn't change how long the GUI went unresponsive so I don't think that's the cause.

```py
import sys
import queue
import random
import itertools
import functools
from time import perf_counter


from PyQt6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt6 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt6 import QtCore as qtc


class SequenceMemory(qtw.QMainWindow):
    
    SQUARE_PER_ROW = 3

    request_round = qtc.pyqtSignal()
    kill_thread = qtc.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.sequence_history = []
        self.sequence_queue = queue.Queue()
        
        self.main_menu()

    def main_menu(self):
        start_button = qtw.QPushButton("Start")
        start_button.released.connect(self.start)
        self.main_widget = self.takeCentralWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(start_button)
        self.show()
        
    def start(self):
        self.setup_GUI()
        self.create_board()
        self.setup_thread()
        self.start_button = self.takeCentralWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.new_round()
  
    def setup_GUI(self):
        self.main_widget = qtw.QWidget()
        self.main_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.main_widget.setLayout(qtw.QGridLayout())
        self.main_widget.layout().setSpacing(0)
        self.main_widget.layout().setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 10)

    def setup_thread(self):
        self.create_sequence_worker = CreateSequenceWorker()
        self.create_sequence_worker_thread = qtc.QThread()
        self.create_sequence_worker.moveToThread(
            self.create_sequence_worker_thread
        )
        self.create_sequence_worker_thread.start()
        
        self.create_sequence_worker.show_block.connect(self.update_board)
        self.create_sequence_worker.hide_block.connect(self.update_board)

        self.request_round.connect(self.create_sequence_worker.create_sequence)


    def create_board(self):
        self.buttons = [
            tuple(
                qtw.QPushButton()
                for _ in range(self.SQUARE_PER_ROW)
            )
            for _ in range(self.SQUARE_PER_ROW)
        ]

        for row, column in itertools.product(
            range(self.SQUARE_PER_ROW), repeat=2
        ):
            button = self.buttons[row][column]
            button.setStyleSheet(
                """
                background-color: rgb(186, 196, 255);
                border: 5px solid white;
                border-radius: 15px;
                """
                )
            button.setMinimumHeight(150)
            self.main_widget.layout().addWidget(
                button, row, column, 1, 1
            )

    def update_board(self, mode: int, row: int, column: int):
        if mode:
            button = self.buttons[row][column]
            button.setStyleSheet(
                """
                background-color: rgb(186, 255, 196);
                border: 5px solid white;
                border-radius: 15px;
                """
                )
        else:
            button = self.buttons[row][column]
            button.setStyleSheet(
                """
                background-color: rgb(186, 196, 255);
                border: 5px solid white;
                border-radius: 15px;
                """
                )
        
    def new_round(self):
        self.request_round.emit()

    def closeEvent(self, a0: qtg.QCloseEvent):
        self.kill_thread.emit()
        self.create_sequence_worker_thread.quit()
        self.main_menu()


class CreateSequenceWorker(qtc.QObject):
    queue_ready = qtc.pyqtSignal(queue.Queue)
    show_block = qtc.pyqtSignal(int, int, int)
    hide_block = qtc.pyqtSignal(int, int, int)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.kill = False
        self.sequence_history = []
        self.sequence_queue = queue.Queue()
    
    def sleep(self, duration: float):
        start_time = perf_counter()
        while perf_counter() - start_time < duration:
            if self.kill:
                return False
        return True

    def create_sequence(self):
        self.sleep(0.5)
        for row, column in self.sequence_history:
            self.sequence_queue.put((row, column))
            
            self.show_block.emit(1, row, column)
            if self.sleep(0.5):
                self.hide_block.emit(0, row, column)
            else:
                return

        i = 0
        while i < len(self.sequence_history) - self.sequence_queue.qsize() + 1:
            row, column = random.randrange(3), random.randrange(3)
            if self.sequence_history and (row, column) == self.sequence_history[-1]:
                continue

            self.sequence_history.append((row, column))
            self.sequence_queue.put((row, column))
            i+=1
            
            self.show_block.emit(1, row, column)
            if self.sleep(0.5):
                self.hide_block.emit(0, row, column)
            else:
                return

        self.queue_ready.emit(self.sequence_queue)


    def kill_thread_event(self):
        self.kill = True


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.setMinimumHeight(450)
        self.setMinimumWidth(450)
        self.setWindowFlags(qtc.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.widget = SequenceMemory()
        self.layout().addWidget(self.widget)

        self.show()
    
    def closeEvent(self, a0) -> None:
        self.widget.close()
        return super().closeEvent(a0)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Above is as minimal as I could get the program to be, without diverging too far away from the program's structure. The full program (in a single file) can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/7FPuzmwq).

Comment: You don't need threading for this (and you should certainly not use `perf_counter`). Just use QTimer. You should also not set the central widget of a QMainWindow as another QMainWindow, unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Comment: @musicamante can you please hint me on how I would implement it? "central widget of a QMainWindow as another QMainWindow" I see, I'll change it to a QWidget then.

Comment: Also, can I ask why? For the two "should not"s that you mentioned.

Comment: Just use a QTimer with the `singleShot` flag set, then create the random sequence as a list, use a reference index when starting iteration, and connect the timer with a function that "plays" the square at the index and increments it, if the index is not the last element of the sequence, start again the timer. 1. just use `time.sleep()`; 2. because a main window is intended as a top level widget, it has its own private layout and supports features like menus, toolbars, etc, which you clearly don't need not only for the *actual* main window, but also not for the "inner" window.

Comment: Besides, a QMainWindow should contain a QWidget, not the other way around. Also, `takeCentralWidget()` is used for the wrong reason and in the wrong way. If you want to "switch" widgets, use [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html). Also, the `released` signal is not suggested for "clicking", as it is emitted also when the mouse moves outside of the button while the mouse button is still pressed; use the `clicked` signal instead.

Comment: @musicamante say I wanted to add functionality of choosing more than one game from `main.py`, i.e. a game other than `SequenceMemory`, would I also use `QStackedWidget` for it or would there be something else for that? I was wondering if `QStackedWidget` with all the games loaded would be memory heavy or something.

Comment: Unless you plan to have *hundreds* of games, that's the last of your concerns. And, btw, it wouldn't change anything from your current attempt (keeping a reference to `main_widget`). You could just remove *and delete* the widget when you want to go back to the main menu, but, as said, unless you plan to have several hundreds or thousands of those games, each one with a *very* complex structure (which isn't your case), that wouldn't be an issue for any pretty decent computer or device. Just remember that you don't need to always create new pages, it works like a tab widget, but without tabs.